rate=1/t vs rate=concentration/t when calculating rate of reaction
What is the difference between them, and when tackling questions how do i know when rate is 1/t or when rate is concentration/t?
Below are two questions along with their answers, but i don't know how total volume being constant leads to rate=conc/t for question 9 and for 12, how amount of iodine formed being fixed leads to it being 1/t.




